# Angular not releasing components when using routing?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular-routing

I have an app that uses routing to display various pages. I'm having some severe memory leak issues where the app will gradually (or rapidly!) gobble RAM until the browser quits.

I worked with another dev who noticed that the components created don't seem to be released when routing to another component. Is this a thing with angular routing that has to be accounted for somehow?

Notice that, in this [minimal reproduction](https://github.com/TheGameKnave/testangularroutingapp), component1 and component2 are both in the heap snapshot after clicking one, then the other.
[image]

Answer (score -2):

when you navigate away from the route(component) you should unsubscribe the subscription in the component.  you should add observable in the subscription and unsubscribe in the ngOnDestroy life cycle hook.

Comment: I'm aware of the need to unsubscribe. My minimal reproduction has no subscriptions and still retains references to components that should have been destroyed.

Comment: are you using any route reuse strategy in application?

Angular offers a route reuse strategy that can help you manage components' lifecycle. By default, Angular destroys and re-creates components when routing to a different component. However, you can customize this behavior using route reuse strategies like DetachedRouteHandle. Make sure you are not unintentionally retaining components in memory by incorrectly configuring these strategies.

Comment: If that's something that must be opted in, no; it doesn't exist anywhere in my app or in the minimal reproduction.